# how can i use django-tokenapi through jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-views

I'm trying to access the link with curl command as curl -d "user=1&token=3wk-e7621e890e5b8db28948" http://task.woo.gy/api4/index.json its working fine 
and the output is

{"test1": 49, "test2": "awesome", "success": true}

but i am not getting it how to work with this api in $.ajax

And when i'm directly accessing this link
http://task.woo.gy/api4/index.json

It gives me message "Must include 'user' and 'token' parameters with request."

code for creating index

```
from tokenapi.decorators import token_required
from tokenapi.http import JsonResponse, JsonError

@token_required
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {
                'test1': 49,
                'test2': 'awesome',
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        return JsonError("Only POST is allowed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not being blocked by same-origin policy, try

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://task.woo.gy/api4/index.json",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
       user: "1",
       token: "3wk-e7621e890e5b8db28948", 
    }
});
```